# Message box does not appear or appears twice sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have two problems:

First, in microsoft edge browser when I select a language from the message box, message box appears twice, how can I prevent this?

Second, in google chrome and fire fox browsers the message box does not appear also when I change the language for some language but not English or German.

Maybe someone can help please.

Thank you.

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/m/MessageBox"
], function(UIComponent, MessageBox) {
    "use strict";
   
    return UIComponent.extend("com.example.FLPPlugins.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        init: function() {
       
            var languageParam = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
            var supportedLanguages = ['en-EN', 'de-DE', 'de', 'en', 'En', 'DE', 'en-US'];
            console.log("Language from URL:", languageParam);
         if (supportedLanguages.indexOf(languageParam) === -1) {
                MessageBox.information(
                    this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("msgBox"), {
                        actions: [this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("deButtonText"), this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("enButtonText")],
                        title: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("langSelection"),
                        emphasizedAction: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("enButtonText"),

                        onClose: function (oAction) {
                            if (oAction === this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("deButtonText") || oAction === this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("enButtonText")) {
                                this.onPressButton(oAction);
                                
                        }
                        
                    }.bind(this),
                    
                    })
            }
          
        },
    onPressButton: function (selectedAction) {
           
            var language = (selectedAction === this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("deButtonText")) ? "de-DE" : "en-EN";
            window.location.search = 'sap-language=' + language;
            sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage(language);
             
        }
        
    });
});
```